# 'imread' function in MATLAB gives image data.what this image data is?is that intensity of pixels?and how MATLAB computes this data?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

i checked imread function code but couldnt understand how it is calculating the data from given image.Please explain.

Answer (score 2):

'imread' function just read the RGB(in case of color image) or black/white(in case of black and white image) value of each pixel in image and shows it in a matrix format.
it is not 'calculating' these values its just reading them from the image/path you provide to imread function.